# Pay-Pal Dropdown Description on Review Page

Tags: wordpress, paypal, payment

I used the paypal auto generated dropdown list and the code below is what it generated.  It works great but when you select an option and get to the pay-pal review page it does not show the description for the selected option.  I can not seem to fidure out how to make it work.  I am hoping someone here will be able to help me.

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="emailaddress@yahoo.com">
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>PURCHASE A RATE OPTION</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><select name="os0">
        <option value="HOURLY">HOURLY $50.00 USD</option>
        <option value="1/2 HOURLY">1/2 HOURLY $30.00 USD</option>
        <option value="MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY">MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY $160.00 USD</option>
        <option value="MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY">MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY $80.00 USD</option>
        <option value="SKYPE MONTH HOURLY">SKYPE MONTH HOURLY $30.00 USD</option>
        <option value="SKYPE 1/2 HOURLY">SKYPE 1/2 HOURLY $20.00 USD</option>
        <option value="SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY">SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY $80.00 USD</option>
        <option value="SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY">SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY $60.00 USD</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="HOURLY" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="HOURLY" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="50.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="1/2 HOURLY" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="30.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="160.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select3" value="MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount3" value="80.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select4" value="SKYPE MONTH HOURLY" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount4" value="30.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select5" value="SKYPE 1/2 HOURLY" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount5" value="20.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select6" value="SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount6" value="80.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select7" value="SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount7" value="60.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0" />
    <input type="image" style="height:47px; width:171px;" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" />
    <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

after a bit of research this is what I came up with:

Altering the price doesn't seem to be allowed.

- Option fields cannot be used for options that will alter the item's price

  *Source: [Using Options Fields on Your
  Website](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_options_help_outside)*

However, you can try restructuring the flow of your form. Here is an example of how to use option fields (from the same link):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size">Size</td>
    <td>
    <select name="os0">
     <option value="Select a Size">Select a Size
    <option value="Small">Small
    <option value="Medium">Medium
    <option value="Large">Large
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Color" maxlength="200">Color</td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="os1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This example defines two custom inputs: one for Size and one for Color. Keep in mind that regardless of whether you use selects or text inputs, the values can be modified by the user via console/inspect element (probably why they don't allow price alterations).

There are basically three parts to each variable, both which share an index. Each pair consists of an onX and osX field name (X is the index such as 0 and 1 in the example).

- onX is uses to define a field's name
- osX is used to define the value (whether that be a select, input, etc).

*Note: I'm not sure if onX variables need to be defined first, I would since they are in the example that way on their site, but it **shouldn't** matter.*

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a drop-down that modifies the price -- but only one.  In fact, the example you posted is almost there -- you're just missing one field: the name of the option that the buyer is selecting (`on0`).  Here's a "fixed" example:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="emailaddress@yahoo.com">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>PURCHASE A RATE OPTION</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="os0">
    <option value="HOURLY">HOURLY $50.00 USD</option>
    <option value="1/2 HOURLY">1/2 HOURLY $30.00 USD</option>
    <option value="MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY">MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY $160.00 USD</option>
    <option value="MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY">MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY $80.00 USD</option>
    <option value="SKYPE MONTH HOURLY">SKYPE MONTH HOURLY $30.00 USD</option>
    <option value="SKYPE 1/2 HOURLY">SKYPE 1/2 HOURLY $20.00 USD</option>
    <option value="SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY">SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY $80.00 USD</option>
    <option value="SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY">SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY $60.00 USD</option>
  </select></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Selected service option" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Service Payment" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="HOURLY" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="50.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="1/2 HOURLY" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="30.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="160.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_select3" value="MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount3" value="80.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_select4" value="SKYPE MONTH HOURLY" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount4" value="30.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_select5" value="SKYPE 1/2 HOURLY" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount5" value="20.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_select6" value="SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT HOURLY" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount6" value="80.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_select7" value="SKYPE MONTH CONTRACT 1/2 HOURLY" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount7" value="60.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0" />
<input type="image" style="height:47px; width:171px;" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" />
<img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" border="0" />
```